# grails web service json id field

Tags: json, grails

I've created a small web service that returns some json, and the returned json value looks like:

```
[{"class":"simple.web.service.Stock","id":null,"name":"GOOG","price":123.45},   {"class":"simple.web.service.Stock","id":null,"name":"APPL","price":345.67}]
```

My object does not contain an *id* field. Where does that come from? And how should it be populated?

Also, is included the *class* field standard? What if I don't want to include that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` attribute is created by default on domain objects, just like `version` (unless you specifically tell it not to include `version`).  Both are set up and maintained automatically under normal usage.  You can control how the id is created/populated if you want - see the [manual](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#identity).

The JSON constructor does not return the actual id or version by default for security reasons.  To include them or to not include other items you will probably need to create custom JSON marshallers.

Something like this in your Bootstrap to only include `name` and `price`:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
class BootStrap {
    def init = {servletContext ->
        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Stock) {
            def returnArray = [:]
            returnArray['name'] = it.name
            returnArray['price'] = it.price
            return returnArray
    }
```

}

Comment: Kelly, thanks. So can I override id if I want to? Say my object has an "id" field? Or is that generally used for internal usage by grails.

Comment: `id` is the generally used field for Grails and I've never tried to create my own column called `id` - although I've used the id mapping to change the behavior occasionally.  You can change how it is generated (using the `id generator` mapping), it's column in the table - especially useful when you are mapping legacy tables (using the `id column` mapping) and making a composite key (using the `id composite` mapping). Depending on how you map your id you might not get an actual `id` column in the database.